# matlab using cell2mat and reshape data to other form

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have cell array

```
  Columns 1 through 6

    [8x8 uint8]    [8x8 uint8]    [8x8 uint8]    [8x8 uint8]    [8x8 uint8]    [8x8 uint8]

  Columns 7 through 8

    [8x8 uint8]    [8x8 uint8]
```

if I use cell2mat function, I get this

```
     Columns 1 through 18

0    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
0    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    1    0
0    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    1    1    0    1    0    1    0    1
0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
0    1    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    0    0
0    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
0    1    1    0    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    0    1
0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    1
```

Columns 19 through 36

```
1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
1    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    0
1    1    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    1    1    1
1    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    1    0
0    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    0    0    1    1    0
0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    1    1
```

Now I want matrix with 8 columns. 
What I want is this

```
0    1    0    1    0    0    1    0
0    1    1    1    0    0    1    1
0    1    1    1    0    1    0    1
0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0
0    1    1    1    1    0    0    1
0    1    1    0    1    1    1    1
0    1    1    0    1    1    0    1
0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0

0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1
1    1    0    0    0    1    0    1
1    0    1    1    0    1    0    1
1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
1    0    0    0    1    1    0    1
1    0    1    1    0    0    0    1
1    1    1    1    0    1    0    1
1    1    0    0    1    1    0    1
```

.
.
.
.
.

Comment: Rather than a screenshot, a copy/paste of the actual text, properly formatted, is preferred.

Comment: Thanks. And actually, even better is a small, reproducible example. You can try to simplify your example. See my answer for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just transposing your cell array and then passing it to cell2mat will probably be enough.

Another (less preferred, loops are generally not welcome in MATLAB) solution is to loop over your cell array and use matrix concatenation. If your cell array has name ca, this will do the thing:

```
imat = []; for i = 1:numel(ca); imat = [imat; ca{i}]; end
```

The answer will be in imat.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly, you simply need to transpose the cell array before transforming it. See the following example (I edited the actual output to compress the display a bit):

```
> a
a = 
{
  [1,1] =
     1   0   0
     0   1   0
     0   0   1
  [1,2] =
     2   0   0
     0   2   0
     0   0   2
  [1,3] =
     3   0   0
     0   3   0
     0   0   3    
}
> cell2mat(a)
ans =
   1   0   0   2   0   0   3   0   0
   0   1   0   0   2   0   0   3   0
   0   0   1   0   0   2   0   0   3

> cell2mat(a')
ans =
   1   0   0
   0   1   0
   0   0   1
   2   0   0
   0   2   0
   0   0   2
   3   0   0
   0   3   0
   0   0   3
```

Note that using reshape brings another ordering:

```
> reshape(cell2mat(a), 9,3)
ans =
   1   2   3
   0   0   0
   0   0   0
   0   0   0
   1   2   3
   0   0   0
   0   0   0
   0   0   0
   1   2   3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reshape function.

```
tmp = cell2mat(...);

res = reshape(tmp, numel(tmp)/8, 8);
```